# Ad Gallery center thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html-lists, gallery, center

I am using jquery ad gallery for my image gallery. I was wondering if there's a way to center the film strip or the thumbnails? Like for example there's only one image then it should appear on the center, not on the left. Thanks in advance! :) Plugin Jquery Page http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Alter the following two classes in jquery.ad-gallery.css:

```
  .ad-gallery .ad-thumbs .ad-thumb-list {
    /*float:left;*/
    width: 9000px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
  }
    .ad-gallery .ad-thumbs li {
       display:inline-block;
       /*float:left;*/
       padding-right: 5px;
    }
```